# Сохранение введённой с экрана информации в текстовый файл с применением различных стилей

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtextedit

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать в *Python3* форматированный вывод в текстовый файл. С помощью *PyQt5* создал диалоговое окно, в котором вводятся данные. Теперь эти данные нужно сохранить в текстовом файле с использованием разных стилей.

Стандартными средствами *Python3* с помощью метода `write` текст сохраняется без стилей. Нужно же его сохранить с форматированием, чтобы информация легче читалась.

Т.е. нужно сохранить в файле текст с использование разных шрифтов, жирного шрифта и подчёркивания. Стандартными средствами, так понимаю, это не сделать. Тогда какой лучше и проще воспользоваться библиотекой *PyQt5*, *Tkinter* или другую посоветуете? 
И, вкратце, как это реализуется в конкретной библиотеке.

Обшарил весь инет. Ни где на эту тему, как ни странно, ни чего нет. Что неужели так всё просто? Или ни кому не нужно было, что тоже странно.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Объясните, что вы понимаете под _сохранить в текстовом файле с использованием разных стилей_?

Comment: Я имею ввиду сохранить введённый в экранной форме текст в текстовый файл с использованием стилей полужирный, курсив, подчёркивание, а также желательно иметь возможность использования различных шрифтов: Arial, Times New Roman и т.п.

Comment: Сюда же нужно добавить изменение размера шрифта текста, сохраняемого в файле.

Comment: То, что вы ищете, называется [языком разметки текста](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Есть популярная библиотека Sphinx для работы с языками разметки в Python.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если человек уже использует Qt, в котором есть средства и методы для работы с rich text, то зачем ему ещё огород из дополнительных библиотек городить?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите сохранить вместе с содержательной частью текста его оформление (цвет, размер, тип шрифта и т.д.), то простого текстового файла вам будет мало. Самый простой и доступный вариант использовать формат [html](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/b-htmlstyles.htm).

Используйте класс `QTextEdit` ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qtextedit.html)). Обратите внимание на методы:

```
QString QTextEdit::toHtml() const - возвращает содержимое в виде строки (как стилизованный текст в формате html);

void QTextEdit::setHtml(const QString &text) - устанавливает новое содержимое из строки text.
// Входная строка text интерпретируется как стилизованный текст в формате html.
```

Вывод `toHtml()` можно сохранить в текстовом файле.

Привожу пример кода (python 2.7.12, Qt4):

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_textedit = QTextEdit()

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.m_textedit)
        btn = QPushButton('toHtml')
        self.layout().addWidget(btn)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.toHtml)

    def toHtml(self):
        print(self.m_textedit.toHtml())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wgt = MainWidget()
wgt.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Это код С++ ? У меня на Python3 программа.

Comment: Т.е. я смогу после этого использовать toHtml() для сохранения в файл и мне не нужно будет создавать новый класс для работы с файлом?

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Буду пробовать!

Comment: Нет в питоне класса `QTextEdit`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, позвольте не согласиться с вашим утверждением. В вопросе стоит метка pyqt. Добавил код в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

К ответу @aleks.andr особо добавить нечего. Вот пример `записи` данных в файл, а также `чтение` из файла и добавление в `QTextEdit`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QWidget, QGridLayout

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.textEditIn = QTextEdit()
        btnTo = QPushButton('toHtml')
        btnTo.clicked.connect(self.toHtml)

        self.textEditOut = QTextEdit()
        btnFrom = QPushButton('fromHtml')
        btnFrom.clicked.connect(self.fromHtml)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEditIn, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEditOut, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(btnTo, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(btnFrom, 1, 1)

    def toHtml(self):
        with open('textEdit_toHtml.html', 'w')as f:
            f.write(self.textEditIn.toHtml())

    def fromHtml(self):
        with open('textEdit_toHtml.html', 'r')as f:
            self.textEditOut.setHtml(f.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wgt = MainWidget()
    wgt.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]